# How to deploy custom theme in alfresco share for windows?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created one custom theme with help of eclipse and alfresco sdk. After successfully build it genarate amp and zip file. How can i deploy for share in alfresco for windows?

I have tried to put in the  Tomcat\webapps\share\themes and Tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\lib folder but it didn't work.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use the [MMT (Module Management Tool)](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Module_Management_Tool) as normal?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  i am new to alfresco. I use your hint and with helps of alfresco-mmt-4.2.0.jar              java -jar alfresco-mmt-4.2.0.jar install D:\Alfresco\amps_share\alfrescoThemes_myFirstTheme.amp D:\Alfresco\Tomcat\webapps\share.war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use alfresco-mmt.jar to deploy amp file for custom theme. I use below command. and restart my server. It work.

```
java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install D:\Alfresco\amps_share\alfrescoThemes_myFirstTheme.amp D:\Alfresco\Tomcat\webapps\share.war

java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install <amp file path> <destination war file path>
```

Thanks Gagravarr for your hint.